# Empty STARTED task in Django Admin Monitor

Tags: python, celery

Have empty record in Django Admin Monitor in Tasks section. It appears once per few hours. Everything works good, but looks like sometimes data is missed. 
Backend is custom for Amazon SQS. I am almost sure that problem is here, but I can't reproduce this. Maybe some one have proposition what can cause such behavior or how can I get more information?

Now have CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT = True, can turning this on give more information?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

sometime happened also to me, but only when I'm playing with the cam, sometimes when I stop it and restart after a bit seems that cam lost some info.
I think that your celery cam sometime miss some infos or don't  receive some signal for some reason. Make also sure that you have just one celerycam process running on all your servers.

Comment: Thx for answer. I've found out that info exists at the beginning and disappeared after few seconds.